# Extracting value from JSON string provokes error message T-SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, base64

**Situation:**

I am trying to join a table with ids to another table with ids and a column that is stored in base64 value. I decoded it and used `JSON` functions to extract a value from key 'a' of the `JSON` string. I got the famous error message:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '(' is found at position 1.

After browsing similar mistakes online, i added the `ISJSON() > 0` as it should exclude the error message - but it didn't.

```
SELECT 
    u.ids,
    base2.ExtractedValue
FROM #ids AS u
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT base.Ids, JSON_VALUE(base.Base64Decoded, '$.a') as ExtractedValue
        FROM (
                SELECT 
                    ids,
                    convert(
                        varchar(MAX),
                        CAST('' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("value"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')
                        ) AS Base64Decoded
                FROM base64info
                ) AS base
        WHERE ISJSON(base.Base64Decoded) > 0 
            AND base.Base64Decoded is not null
        ) AS base2 ON u.ids=base2.ids
WHERE base2.ExtractedValue IS NOT NULL
```

What am it doing wrong?

Comment: Does `CASE WHEN ISJSON(base.Base64Decoded) = 1 THEN  JSON_VALUE(base.Base64Decoded, '$.a') END as ExtractedValue` solve the issue? In general you can't rely on filters being pushed below calculations

Comment: @MartinSmith so is ISJSON in my where statement now useless?

Comment: probably yes, because the `WHERE base2.ExtractedValue IS NOT NULL` will exclude the ones with invalid JSON anyway now. But it may be useful for filtering these out earlier

Comment: @MartinSmith how? im running it but with over 20M of records, its taking quite long now.

Comment: @MartinSmith it worked, want to add as a solution so i can  accpet it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case statement solves the issue as such:

```
CASE WHEN ISJSON(base.Base64Decoded) = 1 THEN JSON_VALUE(base.Base64Decoded, '$.a') END as ExtractedValue
```